# What do these two PHP errors mean? How can I troubleshoot them?

Tags: php, permissions, ftp

I am getting two warnings, can someone help me understand better what's going on? I'm doing maintenance code work.

This is the first - as far as I can understand, it's a permission's issue - how would I go about fixing this? I'd have to change the actual server settings, correct?

```
Warning: copy(../logos/web_democu.jpg) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/kirby/public_html/members/upload_advanced.php on line 30
```

This second appears to have a failed authentication - I believe the account information would probably have to be written directly onto the page, correct? And I will have to modify it to allow authentication.

```
Warning: ftp_login() [function.ftp-login]: Login authentication failed in /home/kirby/public_html/members/upload_advanced.php on line 33
FTP connection has failed!Attempted to connect to for user
```

Answer (score 0):

You're quite correct on both cases.

For the first problem, you would most likely have to find the directory it's trying to copy things into, and then chmod it so that the copy succeeds.

The second is probably a case of incorrect password (or username). You can probably find the culprit by going to the file mentioned in the error and tracing the error from there.

Answer (score 0):

http authentication has nothing to do with the first error - The userid your webserver is running under simply doesn't have the rights to read the source or write to the destination file in that copy() call. Unless you're using URLs for the source and/or destination, that's a purely LOCAL file operation and has nothing to do with how a user's logged in to your site.

And ditto for the FTP error - you're most likely using missing or invalid credentials to log into an FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is probably wrong permissions in the folder that `upload_advance.php` is trying to write.
You can fix that on the server either via FTP or SSH if you have access to.

The second issue is an error with the FTP connection. The login/pwd is probably hard-coded in the php file, have a look !

Answer (score 0):

The first is indeed a permissions issue.  Whoever is running this script does not have permission to either read from the source or write to the destination, *or* the destination does not exist.

For the second, it looks like you did not specify a user.